# Sql management studio and azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created my database on the azure portal

I connect to the database using SQL server management studio.

When I try and create a view the view builder wizard tool is not available - I have to write the views in sql.

It works fine on local sql severs so its something about the azure instance

Is this normal or have I missed something?

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 1):

There is no designer support for creating views in Azure SQL in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio or in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 or prior. You're going to have to bust out your T-SQL skills to create views.